# Get all the nodes with same index value in neo4j by java?

Tags: java, neo4j

How can I get all the nodes with same index value in neo4j by java?

For example I have an index on `name` property of nodes, and two nodes which both have `name="alice"`. I want to get both of nodes, when searching based on index, in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation on indexing?
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html

```
IndexManager index = graphDb.index();
Index<Node> idx= index.forNodes( "nodes" ); //this is the name of your index
IndexHits<Node> hits = idx.get( "name", "alice" );
```

Comment: thanks,how should I deliver values in hits into Node[] mynode?

Comment: with getsingle method I receieve more than one element error.

Comment: IndexHits<Node> implements Iterator<Node> and Iterable<Node>, so you should be able to just loop through the hits.  If you need it to be an actual array check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754554/reusable-method-to-transform-iterablet-to-t